# Can I use GUID to implement oauth_token or oauth_nonce

Tags: oauth

I want to know how oauth_token, oauth_nonce or oauth_token_secret is implemented.
I have already read the specification about oauth1.0 and oauth1.0a, but i am confused about how they are implemented.
For oauth_token, I just know it's a string, but are there any more information about how it's implemented, for example how Google or Facebook implements it,can it just be a GUID?
For oauth_nonce, as i know, it should be unique per request, but GUID is also unique, can i just use it? From a lot website i see it is a number converted to Base 64 string, why should it be like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that  GUID is unique but usually not totally random. To avoid collisions, some parts of the GUID are based on the MAC address and current timestamp of the generating computer. This makes a GUID easier to guess than a totally random number of the same length.

I think a GUID is ok to use for generating unique non-secret values. They are quite long though.  Given the short lifetime of most kinds of tokens, I guess creating random bits is easier and simply faster, and still reasonably unique. It also saves bandwidth and storage to use smaller ids.

Since you often can't transmit raw bits, Base64 encoding is done to send the random number using only ASCII characters. I've also seen Base62 encoding used for this, which is sometimes more convenient because it doesn't contain any special characters (only `0-9a-zA-Z`).